# jQuery .height() function returns false value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set dynamic height by getting element height and setting this on parent div but when I use jQuery .height() function returns the false value:
For example:-

```
<div style="height: 300px">
    this is outer div
    <div style="position:absolute; height: 400px">
        this is inner div of which i need to read height and set to its parent
    </div>
</div>
```

my jquery code

```
var innerDiv = $("#innerDiv").height();
console.log(innerDiv);
//this is suppose to give 400 but on button click it show 845 and but on second click it shows 400
$("#outerDiv").css({'height': `${innerDiv}px`})
```

Comment: Did you forget to add `id="innerDiv"` to html snippet?

Comment: No i just forgot to add it here let me just update it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your code, but the missing IDs. There must be something else in your script that stretch the inner div height to 845.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing wrong in your code, except the missing IDs, in fact if you add `id="outerDiv"` and `id="innerDiv"` everything works well.

Maybe there is something else in your original script that stretches the inner div height to 845.

```js
var innerDiv = $("#innerDiv").height();

console.log(innerDiv);
//this is suppose to give 400 but on button click it show 845 and but on second click it shows 400
$("#outerDiv").css({ height: `${innerDiv}px` });
```

```css
div {
  /* a black outline to see the DIVs */
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outerDiv" style="height: 300px">
    this is outer div
    <div id="innerDiv" style="position:absolute; height: 400px">
        this is inner div of which i need to read height and set to its parent
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but it is completely useless to complain about this. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin